# How to draw dashed line which wouldn't be changing when scaling

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When I draw dashed line with 'line-dasharray' property, it behaves strange - lengths of line and gap changes when scaling. See the example. Question: how to draw dashed line which has constant line and gap lengths which don't change when I zoom in/out?

//this stupid bot says that my post is mostly code. don't know what's wrong in it,

//but have to add some stupid text lines

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a GeoJSON line</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYXN3b2oiLCJhIjoiY2l5Nmg4cWU1MDA0ejMzcDJtNHJmZzJkcyJ9.WhcEdTYQH6sSw2pm0RSP9Q';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
    });

    map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8,
            "line-dasharray": [5, 5]
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found something that makes it a bit better, but still it is not perfect as dashed lines continue to change with scaling.

A part of the answer is that gaps between lines are specified in line width units and not in pixels. And when the line width is constant (in pixels) and doesn't depend on scaling, it's size (for example, in meters) is getting larger or smaller when zoom level changes. That causes gaps between lines to change as well. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259407/style-line-width-proportionally-to-maintain-relative-size-in-mapbox-gl) you can find a description how to make line with variable width which will depend on zoom level and preserve it's relative size.

Here is what I'm getting applying this approach to my example (it became better, but still line changes when I zoom in/zoom out):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a GeoJSON line</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>

    
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYXN3b2oiLCJhIjoiY2l5Nmg4cWU1MDA0ejMzcDJtNHJmZzJkcyJ9.WhcEdTYQH6sSw2pm0RSP9Q';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
    let baseWidth = 5;
    let baseZoom = 15;

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 
            {
                'type': 'exponential',
                'base': 2,
                'stops': [
                    [0, baseWidth * Math.pow(2, (0 - baseZoom))],
                    [22, baseWidth * Math.pow(2, (22 - baseZoom))]
                ]
            },
            "line-dasharray": [5, 5]
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get much better behaviour (in my eyes) by tweaking the actual dasharray values. By taking the first value smaller than the second, for example `[0.2, 2]`, the scaling makes a lot more sense. This is what they use in the mapbox-gl-draw library.

edit: here's how it looks:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a GeoJSON line</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYXN3b2oiLCJhIjoiY2l5Nmg4cWU1MDA0ejMzcDJtNHJmZzJkcyJ9.WhcEdTYQH6sSw2pm0RSP9Q';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
    });

    map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
 layout: {
    'line-join': 'round',
    'line-cap': 'round',
  },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8,
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2]
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```